Book: Football Hooligans are controlling England
This is what little I remember from a near-future science fiction book I read in the late 1970s. I think the writer and publisher were obscure.
Football hooligans from competing clubs control England and they are at war. The hero is working for what's left of the government. He saves a girl who was detected as a spy because she didn't correctly remember the lines of a particular football team's song.
The hero had to perform a job for the government which included driving over a highway the government still controlled but he is attacked by a group of hooligans anyway.
I may have misremembered and confused that last detail with a scene from a Mad Max movie, however I think I read the novel before I saw a Mad Max movie.
I tried a search using the term hooligans in https://sf-encyclopedia.com/search.php without luck.

intriguing concept, sort of like the gangster planet on STOS (with Vic Tayback as one of the head gangsters -- Oxmyx if I recall correctly was one name in A Piece of the Action). i am guessing beer would be cheaper but within 3 months everyone would be dead. sort of like 28 Days Later, right?

It's possible, maybe even likely, this is Albion! Albion! (1974) by Reginald Hill, writing as Dick Morland.
Quoting a review on Goodreads:

An England it's parliament dissolved, divided into territories, run by the four clubs United, City, Wanderers and Athletic. Hooliganism and fascism the status quo and democracy no more. The club management system as oppressive as any behind the iron curtain and the track suited enforcers of the first team reminiscent of the activities of any non first world secret police force. Expatriate Whitey Singleton finds himself in the last place he wants to be - home! Journalists aren't treated well the best at the best of times and this story is no different he is assaulted, tortured, kidnapped and manipulated from pillar to post by the management, the US consulate and the mysterious Jays.

The book is available to borrow at the Internet Archive, and I found the part where the girl (Hydrangea) is caught for not knowing the words to the song:

'The Management? Why should the Management waste time on you? And what do you mean by "trial"? This is no trial, Our Friend. A trial establishes guilt or innocence. There is no such doubt here. Our labours are all for your benefit. Do you think we derive pleasure from seeing you in those abhorrent colours? No, we do not. We want to help you to be able to wear the one, the only, the True Blue once more. You have been obdurate but we have been patient. We have followed you round the circle of your deceptions seeking a way in. You say you have been a Supporter all your life, yet you cannot sing more than the first verse of our song. You say you are a native of Birmingham, yet your answers to questions about that city are strangely inaccurate. You say you came to Coventry to join this Supporters' Club, yet you entered the campus stealthily and were only detected through the eternal vigilance of one of our Strikers. Why did you come? Where did you come from? Who are you?'


Thank you so much, I'm 90% to 99% sure you gave the correct answer, will look it up a bit before I'll give the definite "question answered" response!

Rereading the novel and I'm 100% sure you correctly identified it while I gave so little information. Question answered, thank you again!

@H.A.Treesong Always pleased to help!

And thanks to this site I've now downloaded another story that I'd never heard of... Albion Albion is now added to my soon to be read list
